# Excel vs Sheets: use case of rand() as autonomous trigger for sheet calculations?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I recently read about a fairly brilliant and novel use of the `rand()` function in order to produce (functionally speaking) real-time calculation on G Sheets independent of the sheet actually being opened.  This got me curious as an Excel user whether any such alike conceptual use case(s) exists within native Excel (i.e., using only functions)?

For reference, [this](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/cell-function-table-of-contents/) is the article I was referring to.

Comment: I don't think so, further down in the article it mentions turning on calculation to every minute, which sounds like a difference between Sheets vs Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Continuously change referenced cell value so formula continuously recalculates.

1. Sheets recalculates most functions when a referenced cell changes.
2. Sheets recalculates volatile functions every time **any** cell value changes regardless if it is referenced by the function.
3. Sheet names are not part of a referenced cell's **value** so the formula **`=CELL("address", Sheet1!A1)`** will not be recalculated automatically if the only change made is to the sheet's name, however the actual cell reference in the formula will update immediately.
4. Any volatile function would achieve the objective because it relies on the fact that both:

   1. **Problem:** The string returned by the CELL function's  **`address`** can be changed without changing the cell value.
   2. **Upside:** The CELL function's **`address`** argument will return the same result regardless of the cell's value or any change to it.

#### Does Excel's suffer from the same issue?

No. In Excel, if you change a sheet name referenced by **`=CELL("address", Sheet1!A1)`** the value returned by the formula will immediately update.

1. This issue that Ben solves seems like an oversight on Google's part.  I get why Google wants to delay other updates like IMPORTRANGE but this one makes little sense. I could see this just being under the radar.
2. Ben's example solution is interesting and knowing about this may be useful at some point.
3. Using multiple volatile functions unnecessarily is typically not encouraged from a performance standpoint because of the constant recalculation. Given the implementation overhead it strikes me that many alternatives make more sense. This seems a bit like jogging around your house all day and night in case an unexpected package arrives and each additional sheet is a neighbor doing the same thing around another house.
4. Outside of that use-case, I'd be interested to hear about any other applications of this.